# Running a program from a makefile

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile

I received this sample makefile from my professor and I'm trying to run it on Ubuntu but the commands I'm typing won't run it. All the files in the makefile already exist and when I type make, it makes the files but the actual program doesn't run. I have tried to type ./a.out but that doesn't run it either. Please help me with what command to type for the program to run.

```
# Makefile for Library Management System
CXXFLAGS += --std=c++11

all: div main
rebuild: div clean main

debug: CXXFLAGS += -g
debug: rebuild

main: main.o controller.o view.o library.o publication.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o lms main.o controller.o view.o library.o publication.o 
main.o: main.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp
controller.o: controller.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c controller.cpp
test_view: test_view.o controller.o view.o library.o publication.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test_view test_view.o controller.o view.o library.o publication.o 
test_view.o: test_view.cpp view.h publication.h library.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c test_view.cpp
test_library: test_library.o library.o publication.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test_library test_library.cpp library.o publication.o
test_library.o: test_library.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c test_library.cpp
library.o: library.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c library.cpp
test_publication: test_publication.o publication.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o test_publication test_publication.o publication.o 
test_publication.o: test_publication.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c test_publication.cpp
publication.o: publication.cpp *.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c publication.cpp

clean:
    -rm -f *.o lms test_age test_genre test_media test_publication test_library test_view test_view_actual.txt

div:
    @echo
    @echo 'X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-'
    @echo '-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X'
    @echo 'X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-'
    @echo '-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X'
    @echo
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: the command after the name a rule should be indented by a tab, but in your snippet I see 4 spaces.

Comment: TAB characters are significant in  `Makefile`-s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a file called 'lms'? Try running: ./lms

The things in the makefile after '-o' specify the output filenames. These are the programs you can run.

Comment: lms is the output file specified by the 'main' target. (-o lms)

Comment: Ugh. It’s a bad makefile and I didn’t notice, hence my earlier comment. The program name *should* be the same as the thing before the colon on the non-indented lines, but it isn’t in this case.

Comment: Ah. You can change it to the target name by using the special variable, '$@'.

Comment: @Breezyb12 Sweet! Please accept my answer when you get a chance.

Comment: @vincent Yes, or better yet not include anything beyond the line `main: main.o controller.o view.o library.o publication.o` (or some variant to use the name `lms`) because [Make can take it from there](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Comment: @DanielH Why not? There are different executables specified. So you could run 'make test_library' to build the test_library executable.

Comment: @vincent And the rule for that should be just `test_library: library.o publication.o` with no build steps specified.

Comment: Never mind about my last two comments; that only works for C, not C++. I thought that implicit rule was good.

Answer (score 1):

The job of `make` is to build the program, not run it, so the makefile is probably working just fine.

You can see from the line:

```
all: div main
```

that the makefile will try to build `div` and `main` by default.

There is a rule for `div` that just prints things to the console:

```
div:
    @echo
    @echo 'X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-'
    @echo '-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X'
    @echo 'X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-'
    @echo '-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X-X'
    @echo
```

as noted in the comments of the other answer, the rule for `main` has the flag to gcc `-o lms` so the actual output executable name will be `lms`.

You should really tell your professor that is is bad form, since a makefile is supposed to build a file with the same name as it's rule. (ie `make main` should build a file called `main`) Feel free to point him here if he disagrees.